# How to export object.assign and use it's content for validation in another function of same file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  otherStates...,
  phase: " "
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    phase: state.phase
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    phase: state.phase
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onStarting: () => {
      dispatch({type: 'STARTING'})
    }
  }
}
const ConnRootContainer = 
      connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
      (RootContainer);
```

I've got a switch statement below and in one *case* I need to assign phase some text.

```
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.STARTING:
      let phase = " "

      if (state.stateOne < state.StateTwo) {
       count = growth(state, 0)
       phase = "START"
      }

      else if (CONDITION) {        
        phase = "PAUSE"
      }

      else {        
        phase = "STOP"
      }

      coordinates = generate(state.coordinates, variable);
      return {
        ...state,
        coordinates: coordinates,
        phase: phase
              }

    case types.OTHER_TYPE:
      OTHER CASE FILES
      }

    default:
      return state      
  }
}
```

Phase name has to be used as a condition in another function of same file.

```
let generate = (data, otherData) => { 
   if({this.props.phase} === "START"){ 
  for (let i = 1; i < otherData; i++) {
    let newX = data[i - 1].x  + FORMULA;
    let newY = data[i - 1].y  + FORMULA;
    data.push({ x: newX, y: newY });
  }
}

if({this.props.phase} === "STOP"){
  while (data.length) {
    data.splice(data.length - 1, 1);
  }
}

return data; 
}
```

The new error is: *this is a reserved word* as phase is not passed to the function. How can I improve my code and use *state.phase* in if statement for validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on conversation with OP, this code takes place in his reducer, and thus the solution below has been updated to reflect a working solution, allowing OP to update state based on `action.type` inside his reducer.

Inside your reducer, instead of using `Object.assign` and then not doing anything with it, you can just put it into the state you return by using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

The key change is following:

```
let phase = '';

if (otherState1 < otherState2) phase = 'START';

return {
  ...state,
  phase
}
```

#### Solution

```js
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;

// Create RootContainer of App
class RootContainer extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onStarting}>Set Phase to STARTING</button>
        <p>Phase: {this.props.phase}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
// Functions for ReactRedux.connect
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    phase: state.phase
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onStarting: () => {
      dispatch({type: 'STARTING'})
    }
  }
}
// Connect React Component to Redux
const ConnRootContainer = 
      connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
      (RootContainer);

// Setup Initial State
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  otherState1: 1,
  otherState2: 2,
  phase: 'NOT SET'
};

// Define Reducer
function myReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'STARTING':
      const { otherState1, otherState2 } = state;
      let phase = '';

      if (otherState1 < otherState2) phase = 'START';

      return {
        ...state,
        phase
      }
  }

  return state
}

// Connect reducer to Redux
const store = createStore(myReducer);

// Pass store to ReactRedux.Provider
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnRootContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/6.0.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

<strike>I'm not entirely sure what `Object.assign` is accomplishing for you. In your one function you're returning an object, but in the other function you're trying to access a property from state.</strike>

I'd suggest you save `stage` into state, so you can access it from there later. Here's a solution:

**Note:** In your second function, you're trying to access `state.phase`, even though you said you wanted to access `state.stage`

#### Original Solution

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      otherState1: 1,
      otherState2: 2
    }
    this.getState = this.getState.bind(this);
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }
  
  getState() {
    const { otherState1, otherState2 } = this.state;
    if (otherState1 < otherState2) {
     this.setState({stage : "START"})
    }
  }
  
  doSomething(data, otherData) {
    const { stage } = this.state;
    
     if (stage === "START"){ 
      console.log('phase is START');
    }

    if (stage === "STOP"){
      console.log('phase is STOP');
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getState}>
          Get State
        </button>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</p>
        <button onClick={this.doSomething}>
          Do Something
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I like this method, but I've got **case** instead of class in my program and I am not sure how to integrate constructor and super into it. Is there any way to export my object after its assignment and then use object as validation in the other function?

Comment: @Johnny, I don't understand what you mean by "**case** instead of class". Are you talking about a _switch statement_?

Comment: Yes, I have a switch statement with classes.

Comment: @Johnny could you add more clarification to your code, showing this in practice, I'm still not fully grasping how you've structured your code. Is this in a stateless component, or something else entirely?

Comment: I've got a switch that returns state, and within one _case_  I need to assign a value - some text to an object. This text will then have to be used as validation (in if statement) of a function outside this switch. My original code is large and will be difficult to export here, hope my explanation makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @Johnny, Why can't you save that "text to an object" into the state as well? Otherwise you'll have to instantiate the object outside the function and assign a value to it inside the function, which is a very messy way of doing things.

Comment: I could do that, but not sure how to use _setState_ and _this._. When I tried adding constructor and super into my code, I got a syntax error. Would be pleased if you could advise me on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185635/discussion-between-anonymoussb-and-johnny).

Comment: Couldn't continue in chat as someone downvoted... is there anything I could do within switch to assign text to object of use this.state method?

Comment: @Johnny Take a look at my updated answer, It's a full fledged runnable React/Redux implementation.

Comment: I've managed to integrate your suggested code, only thing is that: when I use _this.state.phase_ in another function, _this_ is not recognised

Answer (score 0):

Well (given that you can't return it, and it's the same file for both functions) just declare a variable in their common lexical scope:

```
let object;

function A() {
   object = someValue
}

A()

function B(obj) {
   console.log(obj)
}

B(object)
```

Of course you should be sure that `B()` executes *after* `A()`

You can always over-engineer this, but currently I don't see any reason to make things more complex.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to use this in my case. Do you define object globally and return in the first function?

Comment: @Johnny the first function `A` is a closure, which means it's body has access to the surrounding scope (variables). When you call `A`, the value of `object` changes to `someValue` (replace to your value). Then you call `B(object)` and logging the object.

Comment: @Johnny So I defined a non-global, but scope-level (where scope is `A`'s and `B`'s common one) variable, and I didn't return anything from `A()` because from your question it is clear that `A()` already has to return some other value (new state?). Be cautious, what I've wrote is a direct answer to your question, but I am sure is absolutely non-idiomatic for React apps (I am not too familiar with it).